# Unzip S3 File and push back into unzipped file into S3 via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can you unzip a file from S3 and push the unzipped version back into S3 after using AWS CLI ?

Trying the below, no success yet.

```
unzip aws s3 cp https://aws-lake/test/test.zip
```

Comment: You make use of pipe to do it. aws s3 cp xxxx.zip || unzip xxx.zip -d test/ || aws s3api put-object --bucket text-content --key dir-1/ --body test/

Comment: unzip aws s3 cp https://aws-lake/bucket/file.zip || unzip file.zip  -d test/ || aws s3 put-object --bucket  https://aws-lake/bucket/

this above is what I tried and I get 
unzip:  cannot find or open aws, aws.zip or aws.ZIP.
unzip:  cannot find or open file.csv, file.zip orfile.ZIP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need, at the least, to preform three actions:

```
# Download the zip file from S3, note the use of the S3 URI, not HTTPS
aws s3 cp s3://aws-lake/test/test.zip temp.zip

# Decompress the zip file into a temp directory
unzip -d temp_zip_contents temp.zip

# Sync up the contents of the temp directory to S3 prefix
aws s3 sync temp_zip_contents s3://aws-lake/test/test_contents

# And optionally, clean up the temp files and directory
# Unix:
rm -rf temp.zip temp_zip_contents
# Windows
rd /s/q temp_zip_contents
del temp.zip
```

It's possible to write a program to download the file into memory, read the contents of the zip file, and upload the individual files decompressed, but that requires more than a few command line commands.

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot use AWS CLI , but only a python script perhaps?

Comment: You can run those three commands (and the fourth to clean up) at the command line using the AWS cli.  If you need to do it one command, either write a batch file or some script.  If you need to do it without local storage, then yes, you'll need a python script or something more complex.

Comment: thank you for the help here - I am getting  

bad CRC 69f63a37  (should be 1079285c) error after running the second step (ie unzipping)

Comment: That means the file is corrupt.  If you delete the local file, download it again, and get the same exact error (same CRC numbers), then it's corrupt on S3.

Comment: Why did it push out csv file still though, despite through that error?

Comment: Why did what push a csv file to where?

Comment: inside of temp_zip_contents

Comment: If you mean the unzip command found some files in the zip archive, then that just means the corruption in ran into wasn't at the start of the zip file, but somewhere after those files were decompressed.

Comment: I see, so I only will have a portion of those zip files?

Comment: If only a portion is corrupted, then yes, it will only have a portion of non-corrupted data.

Comment: Thank you, at that point I am just out of luck - is there any way to recover a corrupted zip? Or do I have to reach out the the individual whom provided the zip in the first place?

Comment: As far as I know zip files don't have parity or other recovery information, so you need to reach out to whoever created that zip file to provide a not-broken version.

Comment: I will, thank you!

I just wanted to try and load the csv into s3 (not the folder - -that worked) and i get

warning: Skipping file /home/ec2-user/unzipcontent.csv/. File does not exist.

why is that , I know this file exists and this is the location

Comment: Not sure why you want to copy one file after you copied a folder with all of it's files, but if you want to copy one file, use something like `aws s3 cp local_filename.csv s3://bucket/prefix/remote_filename.csv`

Comment: Was just curious - ty!